# Eigen Matrix Smart pointer move construction

Tags: eigen, copy-constructor, smart-pointers

Code as below:

```
// Generate the returns matrix
boost::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd> returns_m = boost::make_shared<Eigen::MatrixXd>(factor_size, num_of_obs_per_simulation);

//Generate covariance matrix
boost::shared_ptr<MatrixXd> corMatrix = boost::make_shared<MatrixXd>(factor_size, factor_size);
    (*corMatrix) = (*returns_m) * (*returns_m).transpose() / (num_of_obs_per_simulation - 1);
```

The point is that I want to return the corMatrx as a pointer, not as an object, to be stored as a member of a result class for later use. Above code seems to make a copy of the big matrix, is there any better way to do it?
Thank you and best wishes...

Comment: Where do you return?

Comment: Are you sure, you actually need `shared_ptr`?

Comment: just part of the code, I need return it to use in some other functions...

Answer (score 2):

Slight improvement to @ggael's answer, you can directly construct your `corMatrix` shared pointer from the expression:

```
boost::shared_ptr<MatrixXd> corMatrix 
   = boost::make_shared<MatrixXd>((*returns_m) * (*returns_m).transpose() * (1./(num_of_obs_per_simulation - 1));
```

Or, you can exploit the symmetry of the product using [`rankUpdate`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointView.html#acc37b0437e0eee05f861bce511df9c77):

```
boost::shared_ptr<MatrixXd> corMatrix = boost::make_shared<MatrixXd>(MatrixXd::Zero(factor_size, factor_size));
corMatrix->selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().rankUpdate(*returns_m, 1.0 / (num_of_obs_per_simulation - 1));
// optionally copy upper half to lower half as well:
corMatrix->triangularView<Eigen::StrictlyLower>() = corMatrix->adjoint();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question as returning corMatrix as a shared_ptr will do exactly what you want, but regarding your product, you can save one temporary using `noalias` and `* (1./x)`:

```
(*corMatrix).noalias() = (*returns_m) * (*returns_m).transpose() * (1./(num_of_obs_per_simulation - 1));
```

The whole expression will be turned as a single call to a gemm-like routine.

To complete the explanation:

Recall that Eigen is an expression template library, so when you do `A = 2*B + C.transpose();` with A,B,C matrices, then everything happen in `operator=`, that is the right-hand-side expression is directly evaluated within `A`. For products, the story is slightly different because 1) to be efficient it needs to be directly evaluated within something, and 2) it is not possible to directly write to the destination if there is aliasing, e.g.: `A = A*B`. The `noalias` tells Eigen that the destination does not not alias and the product can be directly evaluated within it.

Comment: I just worry that this "(*corMatrix) ="  operation would mean a heavy copy of data, so maybe your method solved this already?

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: ok, got it, very clear... Thank you very much...But I am posting another related question... Hope see you there soon...